# How sort by counter , but haven't counter - SQL server

Tags: sql, select, count, sql-order-by, distinct

I have one query like

```
  SELECT         COUNT(ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId) as countShow,ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId as valueId, ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingParentFeatureId as attrId, ShoppingFeatureLanguage.Title as attrName, ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.Title AS valueName 
   FROM            ShoppingFeatureLanguage INNER JOIN           ShoppingProductFeature INNER JOIN           ShoppingFeatureLanguage AS ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1 ON ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId = ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.ShoppingFeatureId ON            ShoppingFeatureLanguage.ShoppingFeatureId = ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingParentFeatureId INNER JOIN           ShoppingFeature ON ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId = ShoppingFeature.ShoppingFeatureId 
  INNER JOIN           Product ON ShoppingProductFeature.ProductId = Product.ProductId 
  INNER JOIN           Company ON Product.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId 
  GROUP BY ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId, ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingParentFeatureId, ShoppingFeatureLanguage.Title, ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.Title, ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.LanguageId,                          ShoppingFeatureLanguage.LanguageId, ShoppingFeature.isConfirmed,Product.MoneyId,Product.TypeId , Company.GeoId , Product.ShoppinGroupId 
  HAVING        (ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.LanguageId = 2) AND (ShoppingFeatureLanguage.LanguageId = 2) AND (ShoppingFeature.isConfirmed = 1)                           and (Product.TypeId = 11)  and Product.ShoppinGroupId like N'mn%'   and Company.GeoId like N'aa%' 
   ORDER BY countShow DESC
```

As it clear I have to sort it by **countShow** and I have to call COUNT(ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId) to select because I can't add it to Order By

So the result is something like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YPD8.jpg)

How can I distinct data or sort them without duplicate data

Comment: Why are you using `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` clause?  Does your query even run?

Comment: Sorry I delete it, I going to edit post

Comment: You asked a bad question because your query is not readable/usable and you used a link for your current results.  That being said, I don't see any "duplicates" in your current output.  If you want to turn this into a single record, change the grouping and aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like below..

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId) as countShow,ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId,.....  
FROM ShoppingFeatureLanguage 
  INNER JOIN  ShoppingProductFeature 
  INNER JOIN ShoppingFeatureLanguage AS ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1 ON ...
  INNER JOIN Product ON ShoppingProductFeature.ProductId = Product.ProductId 
GROUP BY ShoppingProductFeature.ShoppingFeatureId,.....  
  HAVING  (ShoppingFeatureLanguage_1.LanguageId = 2) AND (ShoppingFeatureLanguage.LanguageId = 2) AND (ShoppingFeature.isConfirmed = 1) and (Product.TypeId = 11)  and Product.ShoppinGroupId =5   and Company.GeoId=45  
ORDER BY countShow DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is my question :(